# Display image from attachments in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, attachment

I am trying to display images stored in attachment object for a particular contact using a lightning component but i am not able to do so i.e the page appears blank. Below is my code.

ApexMethod :

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static list<Attachment> getImage(){
        //Id parentId


    return [select Id, Name, ContentType from Attachment 
            where parentid='0032800001EXXan' and ContentType in ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif')];
}
```

Component :

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" 
                    controller="displayAttchmentList" access="global">
        <!--force:LightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,-->
        <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.returnAttList}" value="{!this}" />
        <aura:attribute name="atlist" type="String"/>
       <!-- <aura:attribute name="contactId" type="String" default="0032800001EXXan"/>
        <aura:attribute name="Pic" type="String"/> -->
        <div>
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps" style="background: rgb(159, 170, 181);">
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Id">Id</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Body">Attachment body</div>
                            </th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>



                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.atlist}" var="acc">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Id}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate"><ui:outputRichText value="{!acc.Body}"/></div>
                                </td>

                              <!--  <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate"><ui:outputRichText value="{!acc.body}"/>
    </div>
                                </td> -->

                            </tr>



                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>



        </div>




    </aura:component>
```

Controller.js :

```
({
    returnAttList : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action=component.get("c.initdisplayMethod");

        action.setCallback(this,function(a){

            component.set("v.atlist",a.getReturnValue());
            console.log('rtn value >>>>'+a.getReturnValue());

            //console.log('rtn value >>>>'+JSON.stringify(a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is trying to display the body of the attachment, this is a problematic from 2 reasons:

1. you did not select the body in your SOQL, but even if you did - this should not work, and not a good practice.
2. Best practice for displaying an attachment is formatting its URL path with the attachmentId and displaying it like this (inside your `<aura:iteration>`):

   `<img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + acc.Id}"/>`

Comment: Hi Itai,
Thanks for responding. But, the approach you suggested is also not working.
I tried putting console.log to see what has been retrieved and im getting a.getReturnValue() as undefined.

Comment: check for errors in your response: `a.getState()`